# Getting text from all the links that have the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have filters where I toggle class active on click. On click I would also like to loop through the links that have the class active and make a new array out of the text of those links. But I don't get anything in the console when I am looping through.
This is the code:

```
$('.filter-button').click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  var activeTags = $('filter-button.active');

  $(activeTags).each(function() {
    var tags[] = $(this.text());
  });

  console.log(tags);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: var activeTags = $('.filter-button.active'); if filter-button is class, you are missing a dot.

Comment: you forgot the dot on your selector: `filter-button.active`.  Also activeTags is already a jquery object so you don't need to do `$(activeTags)`, you can just do `activeTags.each` and finally, you are resetting the tags var in the each and it is local to that loop so won't exist when you try to log it

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Hi there, first can you please `console.log(activeTags)` and tell us what u have there. and second 
`$(activeTags).each(function() {
    var tags[] = $(this.text());
  });`
this part is all wrong it should be like this :
`var tags = [];
$(activeTags).each(function(index, value) {
    tags[index] = $(this).text();
  });
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new `tags` variable, local to the `each()` function, for each element. That's thrown away when the function exits.

Your outer `console.log()` is trying to list the value of something that does not exist (since we're no longer inside the `each()` function).

Create, and append to, an array *outside* of `each()`:

```js
$('.filter-button').click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  var activeTags = $('.filter-button.active');
  var tags = [];

  $(activeTags).each(function() {
    tags.push($(this).text());
  });

  console.log(tags);
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class=filter-button>1</button>
<button class=filter-button>2</button>
<button class=filter-button>3</button>
<button class=filter-button>4</button>
<button class=filter-button>5</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!